# Is a vertex in a graph isolated if it has only a self edge?

Tags: graph-theory

Pretty straight forward. If I have only one vertex in a graph which has a self edge, ie. V = {a} and E = { (a,a) }. Can this point be called isolated?

Comment: The answer depends on the definition of "isolated". That might vary by context, depending on what the writer wants to use it for.

Answer (score 1):

If you accept the definition that an isolated vertex has degree zero, then no. A self-loop adds two to the vertex degree.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!