# Isolated vertex, loop, and connected graph

Tags: graph-theory

I have the graph $V=\{a,b,c\}$ and $E=\{(b,b),(c,c),(a,b)\}$.

From the definition of isolated vertex:

"an isolated vertex has no edge",

I can tell that vertex $c$ is not an isolated vertex. What confused me is that if $c$ is not connected to the other 2 point, is this graph a connected graph? Because this graph has no isolated vertex.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What is the definition of connectedness?

Comment: Cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2051323/is-a-vertex-in-a-graph-isolated-if-it-has-only-a-self-edge

Answer (score 1):

Your graph indeed has no isolated vertices. It is not connected: its connected components are $\{a,b\}$ and $\{c\}$.

A graph that has an isolated vertex is not connected, but the converse is not true: a graph can be disconnected while having no isolated vertices. For example, you can take the disjoint union of two connected graphs: the result has two connected components and no isolated vertices. If this is not clear to you, then maybe you are confused about the definition of connectivity.